# Closedness of surjective map of affine spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2 $ be defined by $f(x, y)= (p_1(x, y), p_2(x, y))$, where $p_1, p_2$ are homogenious polynomial of degree $d_1$ and $d_2$ respectively such that $f$ is surjective. Then $f$ is $K^* $ equivariant, where $K$ is the base field. The actions of $K^*$ on $\mathbb{A}^2$ are given by $c.(x, y)= (cx, cy)$ and $c.(x, y) =( c^{d_1}x, c^{d_2}y)$ respectively. Thus $f$ induces a map from the projective line to the weihgted projective line, which is proper, hence closed.

Question: Can we conclude from there that  $f$ is closed?

Comment: No. f(x,y) = (x,xy).

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to put the assumption that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(0)= 0$, then we get a map $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$. Then by the above argument shows that $f$ is closed.